# Change ag-grid-angular-community rowHeight of single row

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid-community in angular project.

I want to increase rowHeight of a particular grid row, pixel-by-pixel. I have created a number spinner, on which event I change row.rowHeight. But this reset the whole scrolling of grid, as data is being replaced.

```
this.rowData[0].rowHeight = 200;
this.rowData = [...this.rowData];
```

So basically my need is :

1. Get existing height of required row.
2. Increase the row height by few pixel. The height of row should increase but should not re-render the grid.

I am stuck on this. Need some help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't know ag-grid, but why do you replace the data? It is necessary? I can imagine, that this step causes the grid repaint itself.